# Issue with scroll down in android Appium WebDriver

Tags: java, webdriver, emulation, appium

How can I scroll down for the element appearance in Appium WebDriver? We are using an emulator for automation.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(androidDriver);
    action.press(0, 500)
            .waitAction(200)
            .moveTo(0, 200)
            .release()
            .perform();
```

Just play with the coordinates to get the desidered swiping.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use `scrollToExact()` or `scrollTo()` functions of the **AppiumDriver**

```
AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver();
```

to scroll when string contains "abc"

```
driver.scrollTo("abc");
```

or for exact string "abc" appear you can use

```
driver.scrollToExact("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.scrollTo(value);
```

or

```
driver.swipe(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y, duration)
```

For reference : http://appium.io/slate/en/0.18.x/?ruby#automating-mobile-gestures

Answer (score 0):

Since scrollTo() and many more related methods are deprecated now with the latest version of appium(1.6.3). You can try the below line of code. It worked for me, hope it works for you as well......you can change the dimension as per your requirements.

```
    Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    //System.out.println("Dimension value = "+dimensions);


    Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
    //System.out.println("Screen Height start Value="+screenHeightStart);


    int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
    //System.out.println("Scroll Start Value="+scrollStart);

    Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
   // System.out.println("Screen Height start End="+screenHeightEnd);

    int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
    //System.out.println("Scroll end Value="+scrollEnd);


    driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,2000);
    sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code to scroll till bottom: -

```
    Dimension size= driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int starty=(int)(size.height*0.80);
    int endy=(int)(size.height*0.20);
    int startx=size.width/2;
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work OK:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Put the text you want to scroll to here\"));");
```

If you want to click on the element after scrolling to it, add a click() method:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Put the text you want to scroll to here\"));").click();
```