# Scroll down with Java using Selenium Web Driver (Appium)

Tags: java, android, selenium, scroll, appium

I'm trying to scroll down in an APK page with Java. I'm using Appium and Selenium.

I tried:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

And `driver.scrollToExact();` commands but they are not supported by "WebDriver".

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with scroll down in android appium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120762/issue-with-scroll-down-in-android-appium-webdriver)

Comment: @JeffC I viewed all of the topics about that, but nothing is solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipe method

```
driver.swipe(startx, starty, endX, endy, 3000);
```

I have found an article which can help you achieve your task :-

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/appium-how-to-swipe-vertical-and.html

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks i saw that but it's for Android Driver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll the page on Mobile application using Appium you can use the below code using Appium driver

SYNTAX :  driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration);

Example :

```
driver.swipe(200, 900, 200, 100, 2000);
```

If you want to scroll the webpage in browser you can use the traditional way of scrolling with using javascript.

Comment: But i'm using WebDriver

Comment: if you want to scroll on the mobile screen then you need to use mobile driver only.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");
```

Comment: unfortunately, again this error :
Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Here is swipe action in all directions:

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction){
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            break;

        case UP:
            endY= (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY  = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);

            break;

    }

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(startX, startY)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
            .moveTo(endX, startY)
            .release()
            .perform();

}
```

this code has some deprecated parts, but tried all other methods, wasn't that efficient as this code.

It helped me in several projects.